# Export SharePoint configuration/setup

Tags: sharepoint-server, configuration, farm-setup

I'd like to save a "snapshot" of a SharePoint farm (installed/activated features, web.config files, SharePoint version, etc.).

The idea is to be able to compare such snapshot with the current state of the farm once an issue is identified and it's not easy to pin point what has changed since the last time the farm worked properly.

Is there any such tool available out there? Or something similar that could serve as basis?

Thanks,
Joao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comprehensive report as you mentioned, You need to use the 3rd party tool called SP DOCKit.

[Generate SharePoint documentation, analyze permissions & compare farms](https://www.spdockit.com/)

Create farm documentation in 3 quick steps:

1. Take snapshot of your SharePoint farm (it will load all
   configuration settings).
2. Click the Generate button and choose export options.
3. Open the documentation file.

here is what you get with OOTB poweShell

[Document farm configuration settings in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff645391.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Looks like a great tool. I'll give it a spin.

Comment: A colleague from work also mentioned this tool (open-source): I've also found this other, open-source, tool: https://spsfarmreport.codeplex.com/

Comment: SPDocKit looks promising but doesn't seem to be as comprehensive and extensible as I need. I asked on their chat whether it was possible to log the status of files in the Hive and they answered this isn't supported. I also asked if it's possible to include the contents of certain SharePoint lists in the report and they answered this is supported, but the answer sounded somewhat uncertain (I guess I was chatting with a rather inexperienced person).

Answer (score 0):

If the server is a VM then the easiest way I can think to do this and capture everything would be to just take a snapshot of the entire VM.

Comment: Comparing the snapshots would be rather problematic with this solution. A tool would still be needed for that.